# Delete polygon using python

Tags: python, bmesh

I have a script that returns the 4 vertices of a polygon. How can i delete this polygon?

I've tried using `bmesh` but need the face index and not vertices.

This is a follow up to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248752/delete-part-of-the-mesh-using-python). See it for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v.link_faces` gives you all the polys `v` is used in. So you just need the face common to all the verts.

```
fs = set(v0.link_faces)
fs.intersection_update(v1.link_faces)
fs.intersection_update(v2.link_faces)
fs.intersection_update(v3.link_faces)

for f in fs:
    bm.faces.remove(f)
```

Comment: Thiago: If you want to use this code in the answer to the original question, simply ignore the `index` argument; replace the `try` block with the first four lines of this code and use `f` as the argument to the call to `to_delete`

Comment: I got "AttributeError: 'int' objects has no attribute 'link_faces"...

Comment: are v1, v2, v3, and v4 vertex indices or actual vertices? if they are indices, you need to replace `vN` in the above with `bm.verts[N]`.  You also need to put `bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()` as a line at the start of the code.